# is a logic to divide a number randomly?

Tags: c#, logic

Does anyone know a logic to divide a number randomly? I need to do this in C#, but it might just be logic here.

Example:

I want to split 10 = 3 + 4 + 1 + 2

I want to split 30 = 2 + 5 + 8 + 4 + 6 + 5

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know how to create random numbers?

Answer (score 2):

Pseudo Code:

```
myNumber = 30;                                //Number to split
int maximumValue = myNumber;                  //Maximum value we can get with rand()
int totalValue = 0;                           //Save our total

while(totalValue < myNUmber)
{
   newSplitNumber = rand(0, maximumValue);     //Use as needed
   totalValue+= newSplitNumber;                //Update our total
   maximumValue = myNumber - totalValue;       //Update our maximum on next iteration
}
```

Comment: Good. Thanks!  I think that solves it.